# Run math on asp variables without getting type mismatch

Tags: asp-classic, type-mismatch

I'm trying multiply discount_v times item_qty + total_discount but i keep getting the error **Microsoft VBScript runtime error '800a000d' Type mismatch**.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong, please! Here is the code I am using:

```
total_discount = (discount_v * item_qty) + total_discount
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
 total_discount = (CDbl(discount_v) * CInt(item_qty)) + CDbl(total_discount)
```

Better yet use these type conversion functions when you initially assign the variables.

Comment: You better first check if it's numeric if you're going to use those cDbl/CLng/CInt, or they'll give errors if empty or null.

Comment: @zee: You are right of course bur that is just a tip of the iceburg, what should happen if the check finds a value is non-numeric?